# Why does the optimizer fix my program?

Tags: c, optimization, segmentation-fault

I've got a simple C program to run some matrix matrix multiplication for some tests:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N  1000
#define R_M 100

void disp_matrix(double A[N][N]);

int main()
{

  clock_t begin, end;
  double time_spent;

  begin = clock();

  int seed = 1;
  srand(seed);
  double A[N][N];
  double B[N][N];
  double C[N][N];
  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
      A[i][j] = (double)rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX/R_M);
      B[i][j] = (double)rand()/(double)(RAND_MAX/R_M);
      C[i][j] = 0.;
    }
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    for(int k = 0; k < N; k++){
      for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
    C[i][k] += A[i][j] * B[j][k];
      }
    }
  }

  end = clock();
  time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  printf("Time spent: %f\n", time_spent );
  /* disp_matrix(C); */
  return 0;
}

void disp_matrix(double A[N][N]){
  for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
      printf("%10.3g",A[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  return;
}
```

If I compile with:

```
gcc -Wall -std=c11 -O2 test.c -o test && ./test
```

The program will run fine, however, if I run:

```
gcc -Wall -std=c11 test.c -o test && ./test
/bin/bash: Zeile 1: 10617 Speicherzugriffsfehler  ./test
```

C will compile fine, but the execution of the program gives me an segmentation fault (Speicherzugriffsfehler). I really can not figure out why it would do it this way.

Why does the optimization "fix" my program and where is the original error. I should have plenty of memory for arrays of such a small size.

Comment: Does it also segfault when `N` is smaller?

Comment: Just because the program doesn't segment fault with optimization doesn't mean it's "fixed". Improper memory references may or may not lead to a segmentation fault depending upon what area of memory they are improperly accessing. The right thing to do at this point is turn off optimization and then use the debugger to find out what line of code is causing the fault.

Comment: No not for N=100, but this doesn't explain why it works with -O2 but not without. Also: 8*3*1000*1000 Byte = 24 MB which is quite small

Comment: Stack overflow typically happens long before 24 MB.

Comment: `24 MB` is small relative to heap sizes, but not small relative to a process stack frames. You should be using `malloc` instead of static allocation.

Comment: Run it with gdb and tell us where exactly the crash occurs.

Comment: It terminates right after begin = clock(); Which is the first command I can run  in gdb. This is the error: Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
The program no longer exists.

Comment: You don't use the result `C`, so the optimizer might remove all the computations. They are not needed.

Comment: That seems to be it.

Comment: running it with gdb, I found that the 1000*1000*sizeof(double) was so large it caused stack overflow, resulting in a seg fault event.   I moved those huge arrays to outside of any function and it ran with no problems,, On my computer, running ubuntu linux 14.04 on a 4 core cpu without gdb, the program took 8.405013 seconds

Answer (score 1):

The root of the problem is the huge arrays on the stack, resulting a stack overflow, leading to a seg fault event,

Suggest move the arrays to file scope from their current main() function scope.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in some of the comments, the array was to big for a static definition. I used malloc() and it worked fine.

Edit:
Also,(as commented) the optimiziation 'fixes' my program, because I don't use C and it is therefore not calculated.